# git-tfs one checkin for multiple tfs projects

Tags: tfs, git-tfs, git-tf

At my work, we have a number of separate TFS projects that are combined together to form our Visual Studio solutions.  These separate TFS projects are maintained so that we can reuse code across multiple solutions.  Admittedly, this was a bad idea, as now when we have to branch we must branch each TFS project individually (we even wrote an app to do this).  We end up with a project structure that looks like this:

```
$/Production/[superproject]/MAIN
$/Production/[superproject]/dev/[branch]
$/Production/[dependency1]/MAIN
$/Production/[dependency1]/dev/[branch/
```

where [superproject] requires [dependency1] within the solution.  We end up mapping all these projects to the same workspace.

I would like to use Git-TFS in order to use Git in my day-to-day development.  So far, the best way I have found to do this is to have a "master" git repo with a submodule for each TFS project.  This way I can branch, diff, etc by using `git submodule foreach`.

Unfortunately, our policy regarding checkins is to have one changeset for a task, even if the changeset spans multiple TFS projects.  This is fine if all my changes are constrained to one TFS project (i.e. one git submodule), but when I have changes across multiple submodules for one task then I don't know what to do.  My current plan is to shelve each individualy using `git submodule foreach 'git-tfs shelve mytask_$name'` and then pull each into my TFS workspace, checking in from there.  That only works for whatever TFS branches I have already mapped, which defeats half the purpose of using Git in the first place.

Has anyone encountered a similar problem?  Are there any solutions already out there, perhaps using the TFS command line & a script?  If not, I suppose I will spend some time creating a pull request for git-tfs.  I am open to using Git-TF if the problem is solved there.

Thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is an effort in this way here : https://github.com/git-tfs/git-tfs/pull/350
you could have a look and contribute ;)

Comment: That's actually my pull request :)

Comment: Oh! yes!! So, what do you wait to contribute! ;)